# Why isn't my Docker image of nginx:alpine (with nothing added) about 40 mb instead of 5mb?

Tags: docker, nginx

I'm trying to understand why my [Docker image of nginx:alpine](https://hub.docker.com/_/nginx) is about 42mb and not about 5mb?

I've also checked out `nginx:alpine-slim` which is smaller, but at the 12mb size.

[image]

Is this because

- default Alpine image is 5mb?
- other Nginx related code and stuff ends up pulling the images up to 12mb or 42mb?

Playing around with the `nginx:alpine-slim` version .. I tried `du -sh` to get the disk usage from the `/usr` folder .. guessing that this is where all (most?) of the nginx executables are?

[image]

So 5mb (base alpine image) + 7mb (this folder + sub-folders) would equal about the 12mb image file size .. which would make sense.

Let's check out the `nginx:alpine` equivalent:

[image]

Whoa! 37mb, so 5mb + 37mb is about the 42mb.

So if I'm reading this info correctly: why is there such a massive difference in the `/usr` folders?

Comment: Please use the internationally agreed SI units. MB=megabytes. Mb=megabits. m=milli. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Megabyte

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Dockerfiles for building these images are public, you can click the tag in Docker Hub to be taken directly to the Dockerfile. For `nginx:alpine`, [that Dockerfile](https://github.com/nginxinc/docker-nginx/blob/321a13a966eeff945196ddd31a629dad2aa85eda/mainline/alpine/Dockerfile) includes

```
FROM nginx:1.25.2-alpine-slim
```

so it is extending the slim image. And then it goes on to install various packages:

```
ENV NJS_VERSION   0.8.0

RUN set -x \
    && apkArch="$(cat /etc/apk/arch)" \
    && nginxPackages=" \
        nginx=${NGINX_VERSION}-r${PKG_RELEASE} \
        nginx-module-xslt=${NGINX_VERSION}-r${PKG_RELEASE} \
        nginx-module-geoip=${NGINX_VERSION}-r${PKG_RELEASE} \
        nginx-module-image-filter=${NGINX_VERSION}-r${PKG_RELEASE} \
        nginx-module-njs=${NGINX_VERSION}.${NJS_VERSION}-r${PKG_RELEASE} \
    " \
# install prerequisites for public key and pkg-oss checks
    && apk add --no-cache --virtual .checksum-deps \
        openssl \
    && case "$apkArch" in \
# ... rest of the file can be see in the GitHub link above ...
```

If you don't need those specific nginx-module packages or openssl in your image, then you only need `nginx:alpine-slim`.

For images where you can't look at the Dockerfile directly, many will include details in the image config that can be viewed with `docker image history`. This also lists the size of each of the layers so you can see which command added how much space.

Comment: Thanks heaps @BMitch! this is some great info. So here's a really _lame_ question now : how do I know if I need those modules? I guess the simple way is it try using `nginx:alpine-slim` and see if my app breaks, I guess! The app is a angular app so I don't think anything special is getting used. I'll find out and report back. But the important thing here is that the `nginx:alpine` has a number of EXTRA modules. 